# Pretty output formatting in Play! Framework 1.2.5?

Tags: playframework, output-formatting

I'd like Play! to pretty format my XML responses. My goal is to create clean, human readable XML services.

By default Play! messes indentation in my hand-crafted XML formatting i.e. if there is a loop within another loop.

Comment: If you use play templates for that have a look here : https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/fH6XljnRacU/WoYd2s9XbTkJ

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using the `renderXml()` function from within your controller action.

RenderXml has several overloaded methods, but I am assuming you are using the one where you pass in an `Object` or a `Document`. If you pass in an Object, it uses XStream to searlize the object to XML. If you pass in a Document object, it uses apache's XMLSerializer.

The method can also take in a `CharSequence` (so String or StringBuffer), so if you create your own XML by hand, and pass it in as a String or StringBuffer, it should output in the exact format that you have sent it in.